# Best way to get a list of parent IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these models in my Rails app:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parts
    belongs_to :course
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quizzes
    belongs_to :topic
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quiz_submissions
    belongs_to :part
end

class QuizSubmission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :quiz
end
```

Now I want to get all QuizSubmissions' course id, i.e.`quiz_submission.quiz.part.topic.course.id` for each quiz_submission.

My current code is `QuizSubmission.all.map{|qs| qs.quiz.part.topic.cours.id}` which is insanely slow, I have also tried `joins`, still did not improve the performance. Maybe I used `joins` wrongly.

Any suggestions? Should I make `QuizSubmission belongs_to :course`? Thanks!

Comment: You could do `QuizSubmission belongs_to :course` *if* a quiz submission has a `course_id`. Can you show what you tried for the `join` case?

Comment: How many rows do you expect your table to have? Did you think about de-normalizing your tables?

Comment: Try: `QuizSubmission.joins(:quiz => {:part => {:topic => :course }}).select('courses.id')`

Comment: @lurker I do not have a course_id, I'm just considering add one if I cannot find a better way to do it.

Comment: @spickermann About a few thousands for now for `quiz_submissions`, the problem is that I get a lot of `Load(Cache) Course` `Load(Cache) Topic` `Load(Cache) Part` and etc., which slows the operation.

Comment: @User089247 Thanks! How should I use this result from joins? I about a little confused what to do next.

Comment: The query I posted above is equivalent to your effort: `QuizSubmission.all.map{|qs| qs.quiz.part.topic.cours.id}` but of course it is better since it uses joins and avoid making n number of queries.

Comment: @User089247 I figured out, just call `course_id` on each element if I alias 'courses.id as course_id`.

Comment: @Zeyu That's what you wanted, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @User089247 yup, that's what I want, I was just confused about how to retrieve course_id, now I'm clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
QuizSubmission.joins(:quiz => {:part => {:topic => :course}}).
               select('quiz_submissions.id, courses.id as course_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Course.joins({ topics: { parts: { quizzes: :quiz_submissions } } }).map(&:id)
```

Comment: I think it's another way around, User089247's answers helps.

Answer (score 0):

If i right understood the problem, that is how to get ids fast without join.

```
quiz_subm_ids = QuizSubmission.pluck(:id)
part_ids = Part.where(quiz_submission_id: quiz_subm_ids).pluck(:id)
topic_ids = Topic.where(part_id: part_ids).pluck(:id)
course_ids = Topic.where(topic_id: topic_ids).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not trying to do this without join, I just want to find a proper way to do it.